# Issue with reading a xml file

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I'm having a problem with reading and processing a xml file, which I cannot solve right now.
The xml has the following structure:

```
<root>
  <test id="1">
    <a></a>
    <b></b>
    <c></c>
  </test>
  <test id="2">
    <a></a>
    <b></b>
    <c></c>
  </test>
  <test id="3">
    <a></a>
    <b></b>
    <c></c>
  </test>
</root>



XmlDocument Doc; int currentid=1; 


XmlNode currentlyselectedtestnode =
Doc.SelectNodes("//test[@id = '" +
currentid.ToString() + "']");

string a = currentlyselectedtestnode.SelectSingleNode("//a");    
string b = currentlyselectedtestnode.SelectSingleNode("//b");   
string c = currentlyselectedtestnode.SelectSingleNode("//c");
```

Unfortunately, "currentlyselectedtestnode.SelectSingleNode("//a")" will read out all "a"-nodes and not only the one that belongs to test-node with id 1. Why ?!
Somehow currentlyselectedtestnode.SelectSingleNode("//a"); works just as if I wrote Doc.SelectSingleNode("//a");

How come ?! How can I make it read the children of the specific test-node only ?ectedtestnode.SelectSingleNode("//c");

Comment: Don't forget to mark your code as such so that it displays correctly. :) Do this using the code button on the editor or I believe by indenting by four spaces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using `//a` in XPath, you are selecting *all* `a` nodes in the document.

If you want the direct child, you need to use `currentlyselectedtestnode.SelectSingleNode("a")`.

See [XPath Syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/xpath_syntax.asp) on w3schools:

> `//` - Selects nodes in the document from the current node that match the selection no matter where they are

You can select all `a` nodes that are under the *current* node by using `.//a`. This will select *all* child `a` nodes of the current node, regardless of how deeply nested they are.

Comment: Or, if they can be nested deeply inside the current node, you can use `.//a`.

Comment: Oh, that gets me closer to the solution.
How come that it makes a difference whether I use 

     XmlNode currentlyselectedtestnode =
     Doc.SelectNodes("//test[@id = '" +
     currentid.ToString() + "']");

or

     XmlNode currentlyselectedtestnode =
     Doc.SelectNodes("test[@id = '" +
     currentid.ToString() + "']");

shouldn't it either way select the same single node ?
When I do the latter I get a "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: @dll32 - In the second XPath, you are trying to get a _direct_ `test` child node. If one does not exist, `NullReferenceException`. In the first, you are selecting _all_ of the `test` nodes in the document that have the `id` attribute.

Comment: Sure, but in my example with ID="1", both examples should get the same node. Might have an error somewhere else then.

Comment: @dll32 - The root node is called `root` in your document. You can reference it using `/` at the start of the XPath or by name. This should work `/root/test[@id = '" + currentid.ToString() + "']`